# CDI and JaxWS and EJB in liberty Profile 8.5.5.0

Tags: web-services, ejb, cdi, profile

I have a big problem with web services in Liberty Profile 8.5.5.0.

I made a simple EJB:

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@WebService
public class MyBean {
    @WebMethod
    public Long getTime() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }   
}
```

This works well if there is no `bean.xml` in my webapp. If CDI is activated I have the following error:

> [ERROR   ] CNTR0020E: L'EJB a ?mis une exception inattendue (non d?clar?e) lors de l'appel de la m?thode "getTime" sur le bean "BeanId(testwlp#testwlp.war#MyBean, null)". Donn?es de l'exception :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
>   at [internal classes]

Anybody could help me ?

Thanks a lot.